# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'as_numpy_iterator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a dataset for CNN classification (with images and their labels) by using the `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` and using this dataset created to make the two NumPy arrays: Images and labels. **Python version: 3.9.5**, **Tensorflow version: 2.7.0**

The code has been working fine for the past few weeks, but suddenly today, it gave out this error (see picture below).

Thanks for the help. [image]

Comment: Post your code, not just the error. `image` has no attribute `as_numpy_iterator` because that method is typically found within `tf.data.Dataset` objects, not `image` objects. If you're using something like a notebook, make sure you're creating your dataset objects.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing these two examples [ Sample 1 ] and [ Sample 2 ], data cannot be iterable as it is not symmetric mapping.

Do they loss of some label when transforming the data from request to response mapping?

Why it took a longer response when the program generated that messages?

It should work parallelly but PC keeps pinging for the answers.

Sample 1: Create a dataset from NumPy array and number as the label.

```
# print( dataset.as_numpy_iterator() )
# <tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._NumpyIterator object at 0x0000019980050F40>
```

Sample 2: Create a dataset from NumPy array and none iterable object.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.constant( 0 ) )
print( dataset.as_numpy_iterator() )
for data in dataset:
    test_dataset_list.append(zip(tf.constant(data, name=str(icount)), tf.constant(data, name=str(icount + 1))))
# Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.
```